# Adding the same context menu to multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, contextmenu, extend

I'm trying to figure out how to include common pieces of code in multiple activities.

More specifically, I have a context menu that I would like to include in several activities.
I saw this, but just don't understand how to extend to multiple activities.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

I have this set up as Menu.java

```
    public class Menu extends Activity{

    // bottom menus
    public static final int Menu1 = 1;
    public static final int Menu2 = 2;
    public static final int Menu3 = 3;
    public static final int Menu4 = 4;
    public static final int Menu5 = 5;
    public static final int Menu6 = 6;
    public static final int Menu7 = 7;


    // / Creates the menu items
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add(0, Menu3, 0, "Create Profile").setIcon(
                this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_add));
        menu.add(0, Menu5, 0, "Log In").setIcon(
                this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_login));
        menu.add(0, Menu2, 0, "Settings").setIcon(
                this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences));
        menu.add(0, Menu4, 0, "About").setIcon(
                this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_help));
        menu.add(0, Menu1, 0, "Report A Bug").setIcon(
                this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_start_conversation));
        menu.add(0, Menu6, 0, "New Stuff").setIcon(
                this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_view));
        return true;
    }



    private MenuItem add(int i, int menu32, int j, String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



    // Handles item selections from preference menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case Menu1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Bug.class));
            return true;
        case Menu2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, EditPreferences.class));
            return true;
        case Menu3:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, CreateAccount.class));
            return true;
        case Menu4:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
            return true;
        case Menu5:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
            return true;
        case Menu6:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, NewAdditions.class));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

if you want to add same functionality in more than 1 activity than create 1 common activity
like BaseActivity and extend that activity will include that common functions in your inherited all activities

for example i have called checklogin function , you can put your menu code here,

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        if (IsFullScreen) {
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        this.CheckLogin();
     }

    // Check login function
    // Your menu code

  }
```

now you can extend it in your activities

```
public class MainScreen extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks all! These have been really helpful. I ended up using both BrennaSoft's xml sample. Then djk's main screen/base activity sample to clean up my code a lot.

Comment: I need to declare BaseActivity in `AndroidManifest.xml`? Or No need of this?

Answer (score 3):

You can define a menu in an xml file and then load the menu in onCreateOptionsMenu. You will still need to handle each menu item in each activity. You could also create a BaseActivity class that handles the menu stuff that each Activity could extend.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/about" android:title="About"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_about"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search" android:title="Search"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/my_location"
          android:title="My Location"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_mylocation">
    </item>
</menu>


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use  a `abstract` class

```
  abstract class BaseMenu extends Activity
  {
         //Initialize your menus

         // bottom menus
public static final int Menu1 = 1;
public static final int Menu2 = 2;
public static final int Menu3 = 3;
public static final int Menu4 = 4;
public static final int Menu5 = 5;
public static final int Menu6 = 6;
public static final int Menu7 = 7;


// / Creates the menu items
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(0, Menu3, 0, "Create Profile").setIcon(
            this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_add));
    menu.add(0, Menu5, 0, "Log In").setIcon(
            this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_login));
    menu.add(0, Menu2, 0, "Settings").setIcon(
            this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences));
    menu.add(0, Menu4, 0, "About").setIcon(
            this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_help));
    menu.add(0, Menu1, 0, "Report A Bug").setIcon(
            this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_start_conversation));
    menu.add(0, Menu6, 0, "New Stuff").setIcon(
            this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_view));
    return true;
}



private MenuItem add(int i, int menu32, int j, String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}



// Handles item selections from preference menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case Menu1:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Bug.class));
        return true;
    case Menu2:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, EditPreferences.class));
        return true;
    case Menu3:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, CreateAccount.class));
        return true;
    case Menu4:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
        return true;
    case Menu5:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
        return true;
    case Menu6:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, NewAdditions.class));
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}}
```

Now extend the class `BaseMenu` instead of `Activity`

I Think this could help you out.